# Options for validating JSON input against a Swagger schema

Tags: java, json, swagger

I need to find some options for validating JSON input against a Swagger schema, e.g. the Swagger provided by IPaaS. I never used Swagger before and my old way to validate was to transfer JSON input to a JAVA POJO first, and then validate that JAVA POJO, is there a tool to validate the JSON input directly in Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first thing to know is Swagger also goes by the new name of Open API (it's a bit more complicated than that as the standard are evolving).

Try this
https://www.openapi4j.org/parser.html

it reads/writes Open API/Swagger schemas in YAML or JSON